# Styling an img element with CSS

Tags: html, css

For some reason the img in my HTML is not being affected at all by my img CSS. It is supposed to be re-sized. What could I be doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/AEPtC/

Answer (score 6):

You misspelled `profile-picture`:

```
<div id="profile-pictutre">
                      ^
```

Here's a fixed version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AEPtC/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) so we can see your code. But have you set the image width/height inline, such as: `<img src="/src.jpg" width="200" height="200">`, if so CSS can sometimes have an undesired effect.

**Edit:** Looks like you had a spelling error? [Fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/AEPtC/3/)

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to set the img `height:auto, max-width:100%`, don't you?

http://jsfiddle.net/AEPtC/7/